# Javascript - how to play french files?

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, nginx, chromium

i have french audio files (a lot of with accent, space, symbols), for example:

```
à l'étranger.wav
```

I need to play that file in chromium or google chrome as below, in meeting demo:

```
  input = "à l'étranger.wav";
  $('#mediaplayer').prop('loop', false);
  $('#mediaplayer').attr('src', 'http://localhost/' + input).show();
  mediaplay= document.getElementById('mediaplayer');
  mediaplay.play();
```

When i use that same code for other files it works, but never worked when its with the file contain abnormal french characters? how can i play it without renaming the original file name?

**EDIT:** nginx runnning as localhost with following config:

```
worker_processes  1;
events {
    worker_connections  1024;
}

http {
    include       mime.types;
    default_type  application/octet-stream;
    sendfile        on;
    keepalive_timeout  65;
    server {
        listen       80;
        server_name  localhost;
        location / {
            root   html;
            index  index.html index.htm;
        }
        error_page   500 502 503 504  /50x.html;
        location = /50x.html {
            root   html;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: At a guess, the problem seems to be the server, not the client. What are you using to serve http?

Comment: Its a local host Nginx server

Comment: Is there anything in the nginx logs that may provide a clue?

Comment: Sir, i have error.log and access.log files in nginx directory, but there is none, to find what is the error in web-server therefore no idea how to resolve it.

Comment: so there is nothing in the access or error log of nginx? That suggests no access was made at all ... is the html file the script is in also served by the same nginx server?

Comment: http://fakedomain.com/run_presentation.html - is executed from Linux apache server in LAN from another PC, and the Wav files are in local PC with nginx.

Comment: If the files are not French, lets say file name is "jaromandax.wav" then it works

Comment: if your markup in the question is the same as in your code,  you are using `\`` "combining grave accent" +  `a` while I guess your file name is just with `à`, "latin small letter a with grave".

Comment: I understand that non french files work, it's ion your question, I don't understand how the log files would be empty, except now you've explained that nginx is used only for the audio files ... in that case, it appears my initial assertion that it is s server side issue was inccorect

Comment: Do you get any errors in the console of your browser?

Comment: Consoloe log say, file not found

Comment: When i open the file manually using file:// scheme in the chromium it works with french accent

Comment: it does not work when i use scheme `http://localhost` to that file

Comment: can you try `var input = "à l'étranger.wav"` ? I used the correct characters that your users will use from an AZERTY keyboard

Comment: Can you download the files in the browser by hitting the URL directly?

Comment: 1) FAIL : var input = "à l'étranger.wav" , no file found in console log 2) FAIL: when i open the url manually in the browser also nginx send 404 not found nginx

Comment: FYI: when i manually remove from the file the name with those chracters then it works: from "à l'étranger.wav" into " ltranger.wav"

Comment: and `"%C3%A0%20l'%C3%A9tranger.wav"`?

Comment: Same, when i send it with URL encoded format then still Manually or Javascript submission both returns: 404 file not found